# Finding inner matches using Regular Expressions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string `"#review?loanId=12-00034&docId=0"` and need to select the loanId (`"12-00034"`) string, how would I use a single regular expression to do this?

So far I can use `/loanId=[\d-]*/` to retrieve `"loanId=12-00034"` but how do I get only the id by itself?  I can get it by nesting another regular expression, but I was wondering if this was possible with only one regex.

Comment: Use a capturing group.

Comment: OK gotcha. Thanks, I didn't know the name of the method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
var query = "#review?loanId=12-00034&docId=0"

var matches = /\bloanId=([-\d]*)/.exec(query)

console.log(matches[1]);

// => 12-00034
```

This is pretty similar to the other answers, here the main difference is I'm using `\b` [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to prevent the regexp from matching the incorrect id in something like `whateverloanId=123&loanId=123-456`

The second difference is my capture group is `([-d]*)`. This means that if your string has an empty loanId like `?loanId=&something=foo`, you won't get a `TypeError` for `matches[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var regex = /loanId=([^&"'\s]+)/;

var match = regex.exec(yourString);

console.log(match[1]);
```

the result is in the first capturing group. Since javascript regex doesn't have the lookbehind feature, this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
/loanId=([\d-]+)/
```

Like this:

```
var re = /loanId=([\d-]+)/
re.exec("#review?loanId=12-00034&docId=0")
  // ["loanId=12-00034", "12-00034"]
re.exec("no match")
  // null
```